# Smooth menu appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to make a menu which slides from right to left a h2 header **and when it done** from up to down information. If clicked different option if menu already exists, is firstly goes up and then left else just as said. So the major problem is that in some ways there need to appear 2 infos instead of one and I can't figure how to do, that all executed one after other. If using callbacks, some of text appears two or more times...

```
$("a[rel~='showinfo']").click(function () {
  var info_id = $(this).attr('id');//getting needed id from menu to show info

  if($('.info_name').is(':visible'))//if already exists - removing
    remove_contact();

  for(i=0; i<contact_status.length; i++){//checking all array for item
    if(info_id == contact_status[i]){//if item exist 
        create_contact(i);//putting it in
        //here starts problems....
        $('#info_name'+i).show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000, function(){
            $('#info_info'+i).show("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
        });
    }
  }
 //$('.info_name').show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
 //$('.info_info').show("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000);

});

function create_contact(id){
    $('.third').append('<div class="showinfo"><h2 id="info_name'+id+'" class="info_name">'+contact_name[id]+'</h2><span class="info_info" id="info_info'+id+'">lol</span></div>')
}

function remove_contact() {
    $('.info_name').hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
    $('.showinfo').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(i=0; i<contact_status.length; i++){//checking all array for item
    if(info_id == contact_status[i]){//if item exist 
        (function ( idx ) { // use a Anonymous funciton
             create_contact(idx );//putting it in
            //here starts problems....
            var;
            $('#info_name'+idx ).show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000, function(){
                $('#info_info'+idx ).show("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
            });
        })( i );
    }
  }
```

ah, I make a mistake... this time should be right

Comment: #info_name and #info_info are different. 2  different elements. One need to appear after first.